# S3 write from Spark fails intermittently with Error code 404 NoSuchKey

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

My spark job (EMR) that writes to s3 every 5 minutes, fails to write a few times every day with following exception. Any idea what could cause this?

Code:

```
    ds.write
      .mode("overwrite")
      .format("parquet")
      .save("s3://....")
```

Exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:285)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID: ABC4A49392884812; S3 Extended Request ID: ed+11111OKdq5jh8qY65Atc5Q33FHxy7Lzm0aWwxiHL9hhOxN+28eEPZobvLveGoJnzCoSEXsH4=), S3 Extended Request ID: ed+11111OKdq5jh8qY65Atc5Q33FHxy7Lzm0aWwxiHL9hhOxN+28eEPZobvLveGoJnzCoSEXsH4=
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.MultipartCopyManager.copy(MultipartCopyManager.java:180)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.copy(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:425)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.rename(S3NativeFileSystem.java:1300)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.rename(EmrFileSystem.java:321)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:457)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:471)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:582)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:545)
at com.amazon.emr.committer.FilterParquetOutputCommitter.commitTask(FilterParquetOutputCommitter.java:119)
at com.amazon.emr.committer.EmrOptimizedSparkSqlParquetOutputCommitter.commitTask(EmrOptimizedSparkSqlParquetOutputCommitter.java:9)
```

Comment: Is the write operation creating new files or updating existing ones?

Comment: This can be due to S3 consistency. enable EMRFS consistent view

Comment: @Stargazer, it overwrites existing files (if any) in the folder

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be a consistency issue. S3 has read after write consistency for new files only. Updated files may take some time to show consistency.

Comment: @UjjwalBhardwaj I will try enabling s3 consistency. Thanks

Comment: Hey, did this fix your issue? @BijithKumar

Answer (score -1):

Surprised the EMR "optimized" committer is doing the rename at all -it's meant to be a "zero rename committer".